# how to find all the methods available in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uisearchbar

I am trying to create a customized UISearchBar. I am not able to find all possible methods using documentation. Is there way to find all the available methods ?.

Comment: This is insufficient? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create UISearchBar 's object 
like

```
UISearchBar *mySearchBar;
        mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        [mySearchBar //Hit Escape Button here you will get all the possible methods of UIsearchBar and its Super class that it can call...
```

Comment: project -> class browser in xcode solved my problem. Thanks :).